# jcmd VM.set_flag, which flags are writable?

Tags: java, java-9, jcmd

I was trying to experiment with jcmd VM.set_flag option. But came across one error saying "only 'writeable' flags can be set". What are writable flags ?

Getting my pid:

```
XXX@XXX-Air:~/javacode$ jcmd -l
6294 Test
6295 jdk.jcmd/sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd -l
```

Trying to change vm flags:

```
XXX@XXX-Air:~/javacode$ jcmd 6294 VM.set_flag ConcGCThreads 4
6294:
only 'writeable' flags can be set
XXX@XXX-Air:~/javacode$ jcmd 6294 VM.set_flag MaxNewSize 1G
6294:
only 'writeable' flags can be set
```

Edit: It worked for manageable flags, below are successful commands.

```
 XXXX@XXX-Air:~/javacode$ jcmd 11441 VM.flags -all | grep MinHeapFreeRatio
    uintx MinHeapFreeRatio                         = 40                                    {manageable} {default}
XXXX@XXX-Air:~/javacode$ jcmd 11441 VM.set_flag MinHeapFreeRatio 45
11441:
Command executed successfully
XXXX@XXX-Air:~/javacode$ jcmd 11441 VM.flags -all | grep MinHeapFreeRatio
    uintx MinHeapFreeRatio                         = 45
```

Comment: VM.set_flag is available in java 9 via http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/228, it is jdk9 specific option. isnt it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writable flags are labeled as `{manageable}`.

You can list all flags with `jcmd 12345 VM.flags -all`. You can then grep for manageable ones (the is on my Oracle jdk8 VM) :

```
$ jcmd 12345 VM.flags -all | grep manageable
     intx CMSAbortablePrecleanWaitMillis            = 100                                 {manageable}
     intx CMSTriggerInterval                        = -1                                  {manageable}
     intx CMSWaitDuration                           = 2000                                {manageable}
     bool HeapDumpAfterFullGC                       = false                               {manageable}
     bool HeapDumpBeforeFullGC                      = false                               {manageable}
     bool HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError                = false                               {manageable}
    ccstr HeapDumpPath                              =                                     {manageable}
    uintx MaxHeapFreeRatio                          = 100                                 {manageable}
    uintx MinHeapFreeRatio                          = 0                                   {manageable}
     bool PrintClassHistogram                       = false                               {manageable}
     bool PrintClassHistogramAfterFullGC            = false                               {manageable}
     bool PrintClassHistogramBeforeFullGC           = false                               {manageable}
     bool PrintConcurrentLocks                      = false                               {manageable}
     bool PrintGC                                   = false                               {manageable}
     bool PrintGCDateStamps                         = false                               {manageable}
     bool PrintGCDetails                            = false                               {manageable}
     bool PrintGCID                                 = false                               {manageable}
     bool PrintGCTimeStamps                         = false                               {manageable}
```

Answer (score 2):

The article over the [VM options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) states this :-

> Flags marked as ***manageable*** are dynamically *writeable* through the JDK
>   management interface (`com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean` API)
>   and also through JConsole.

To find out all such flags you can use [`VM.flags`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jcmd.htm#JSWOR743) that would

> Print the VM flag options and their current values

with the [`-all`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jcmd.htm#JSWOR743) as the option to

> Prints all flags supported by the VM

using the command :-

```
jcmd <pid> VM.flags -all
```